# Eclipse start problem after plugin installation

Tags: java, eclipse

I use Eclipse 3.4.2 and just installed Android SDK plugin for eclipse. But After installation when I start the eclipse, I get error message

[image]

Here is what the log says

```
!SESSION 2011-03-07 11:13:53.163 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20090211-1700
java.version=1.6.0_23
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-03-07 11:13:53.632
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1236)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-03-07 11:13:53.647
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-03-07 11:13:53.647
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins\com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview_10.0.0.v201102162101-104271.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview 2 0 2011-03-07 11:13:53.647
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview 2 0 2011-03-07 11:13:53.647
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview 2 0 2011-03-07 11:13:53.648
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview 2 0 2011-03-07 11:13:53.648
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview 2 0 2011-03-07 11:13:53.648
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.resources_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview 2 0 2011-03-07 11:13:53.648
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.filesystem_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview 2 0 2011-03-07 11:13:53.648
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-03-07 11:13:53.648
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins\com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer_10.0.0.v201102162101-104271.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer 2 0 2011-03-07 11:13:53.648
```

Has anyone faced the same problem?

Comment: Looks like you're missing two jar files, listed in the error messages.  Have you verified that they're present?

Comment: Yes I have those jar files already.

Comment: can it be resolved by changing in eclipse configurations , i am having a same problem, just wanted to avoid reinstalling eclipse and ADT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by reinstalling eclipse , not what I wanted, but I will go with this one at this moment.

Answer (score 2):

A number of people have [reported similar problems](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391495). There are several suggestions in that thread, but no definitive solutions. Only one of the suggestions worked for me - it's a way to revert eclipse to a previous state from the command line. It comes from [this blog post](http://pweclipse.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/working-state-from-p2-update.html).

In a terminal:

1. Go to the folder containing your eclipse install
2. `ls -lt p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/<som_profile_name>.profile/`
3. In my case `<som_profile_name>` was `epp.package.java.profile`, in Paul's blog `SDKProfile`.
4. You should see files like `1372434812558.profile.gz`.
5. Choose a recent one with a date you feel sure is ok
6. Put together a command like:

   `eclipse -noSplash 
   -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
   -repository file:$(pwd)/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/<som_profile_name>.profile
   -profile <som_profile_name>
   -revert 1372434812558`
7. If that doesn't work, try adding `-destination .` (I did it successfully with `-destination`, but I think it should work without)